# Best way to store pdf files in android

Tags: android

IN our application we are getting byte array from server if login gets success. We are converting those byte array into PDF format and storing those files into DB which using internal memory.If files are in KB , application works properly but of files size get increase  in MB then application gives out of memory error.Please tell me how to handle this scenario?How to store files into SD card to maintain security also.It should not visible to outside user.
Please do help.

Thanks,
AA.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at:
[CipherInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html) and [CipherOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html). They are used to encrypt and decrypt byte streams.

EDIT: So here you go!

I have a file named `cleartext`. The file contains:

> ```
> Hi, I'm a clear text.
> How are you?
> That's awesome!
> ```

Now, you have an `encrypt()` function:

```
static void encrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    // Here you read the cleartext.
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("data/cleartext");
    // This stream write the encrypted text. This stream will be wrapped by another stream.
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("data/encrypted");

    // Length is 16 byte
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
    // Create cipher
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
    // Wrap the output stream
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
    // Write bytes
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
        cos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    // Flush and close streams.
    cos.flush();
    cos.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

After you execute this function, there should be a file names `encrypted`. The file contains the encrypted characters.

For decryption you have the `decrypt` function:

```
static void decrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("data/encrypted");

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("data/decrypted");
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
        fos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    cis.close();
}
```

After the execution of decrypt, there should be a file named `decrypted`. This file contains the free text.

Edit: You write you're a "noob" but depending on the use-case of encryption you could do a lot of harm if you're not doing it the right way. Know your tools!

Usage of CipherOutputStream [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#CipherOutput):

SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(y.getBytes(), "AES");

```
FileInputStream fis;
FileOutputStream fos;
CipherOutputStream cos;
// File you are reading from
fis = new FileInputStream("/tmp/a.txt");
// File output
fos = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/b.txt");

// Here the file is encrypted. The cipher1 has to be created.
// Key Length should be 128, 192 or 256 bit => i.e. 16 byte
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES"); 
Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("AES");  
cipher1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher1);
// Here you read from the file in fis and write to cos.
byte[] b = new byte[8];
int i = fis.read(b);
while (i != -1) {
    cos.write(b, 0, i);
    i = fis.read(b);
}
cos.flush();
```

Thus, the encryption should work. When you reverse the process, you should be able to read the decrypted bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Storing on the SD card will make the file accessible to savvy users.  Storing in the db will give you errors like you mentioned.  Probably the best idea would be to go to internal storage.  This isn't perfect (rooted users can browse to the files), but it's probably the best option.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: DB is also refers internal storage.Can you please tell me how can i store files in internal storage. It will also give me out of memory error.

Comment: You are most likely getting out of memory errors if you're downloading the entire byte stream into memory and then saving it into the db.  If you read and write directly from the input stream of your web request into the output stream of your file, you won't be holding all of those bytes in memory and using up all of your allocated space.